# How to use Mockito.verify() on static methods?

Tags: java, mockito

I am working on Junit & Mockito. In my project I have a SocialDataAccess Controller whose code goes like this:

```
public class SocialDataAccessController implements Controller{

private SocialAuthServiceProvider socialAuthServiceProvider;

@Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String provider = request.getParameter("pId");
        String appCode =  request.getParameter("apc");

         * check if data in session is of the same provider orof different
         * provider, if different then remove auth and request token
         **/

        SocialUtility.removeOtherProviderAuthTokenFromSession(request,provider);

        try {
            /** creating the OAuthService object based on provider type **/
            OAuthService service = getSocialAuthServiceProvider().getOAuthServiceProvider(appCode, provider);
            .....
            ........
            ............            
return new ModelAndView("redirect:callback.html?pId=" + provider);
    }

public SocialAuthServiceProvider getSocialAuthServiceProvider() {
        return socialAuthServiceProvider;
    }

}
```

This is what I have done. I have made a request and my request successfully calls my controller. When I try to use `Mockito.verify()` to test whether my static method is called or not, I get an error as shown below.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(
        locations={
            "file:/opt/div/BatchWorkspace/harvest_branch/WebContent/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml"
        }
)

public class TestSocialDataAccessController {   
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();      
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Test
    public void testBasicSetUp() throws Exception{
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/social-connect.html")
                .param("apc","tj")
                .param("src","google")
                .param("pId","ggl")
                .param("cl","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
       .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isMovedTemporarily())
       .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl("xxxxxxxx"));

           SocialUtility sutil = new SocialUtility();
           SocialUtility spy = Mockito.spy(sutil);
           MockHttpServletRequest request = requestBuilder.buildRequest(wac.getServletContext());
           Mockito.verify(spy).removeOtherProviderAuthTokenFromSession(request,Matchers.anyString());          

    }
}
```

The error which I got:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at com.tj.harvest.testcase.TestSocialDataAccessController.testBasicSetUp(TestSocialDataAccessController.java:88)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

    at com.tj.harvest.testcase.TestSocialDataAccessController.testBasicSetUp(TestSocialDataAccessController.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597).
```

My questions are:

1. Can I use `Mockito.verify()` on my method `removeOtherProviderAuthTokenFromSession(request,provider)`. If "yes" How? & If "NO" why? `SocialUtility` is the name of class and the method is static. Request is the same request which comes to the controller. And provider is a string. I don't want to use PowerMockito.
2. I also want to use verify on `getOAuthServiceProvider(appCode, provider)`.
   How can I do this?

Any Help would be appreciable.

Comment: Mockito cannot handle static methods. For that you need to use PowerMock or a similar framework.

Comment: Refactor your code. The need to mock or verify static methods is a sign of bad code. PowerMock is not what I would consider a typical tool, it's a workaround to test bad code. To use them simulatneously, I would tend to create the Spring context manually instead of via the Spring runner, as the PowerMock runner needs to do dirtier work that cannot be easily put somewhere else.

Comment: The object you want to verify comes from your socialAuthServiceProvider. So you have to either mock that or put a spied version of the OAuthServiceProvider there, so that the method call will return it. Mocking it seems easier, but may have side effects.

Comment: I tried this but it says suppose to be called but wasn't called   SocialAuthServiceProvider sap=new SocialAuthServiceProvider();
SocialAuthServiceProvider spy=Mockito.spy(sap);  Mockito.verify(spy).getOAuthServiceProvider(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(String.class));

Comment: I tried this still not working                                  SocialAuthServiceProvider sasp=Mockito.mock(SocialAuthServiceProvider.class);
  Mockito.verify(sasp).getOAuthServiceProvider(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(String.class));                                                                                    error: Wanted but not invoked:
socialAuthServiceProvider.getOAuthServiceProvider(
    isA(java.lang.String),
    isA(java.lang.String)
); @FlorianSchaetz

Comment: SocialDataAccessController mocksdac=Mockito.mock(SocialDataAccessController.class);
  SocialAuthServiceProvider sasp=Mockito.mock(SocialAuthServiceProvider.class);
  Mockito.when(mocksdac.getSocialAuthServiceProvider()).thenReturn(sasp);                     Mockito.verify(sasp).getOAuthServiceProvider(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(String.class));                      still not successful

Comment: Normally, Mockito.anyString() should suffice here as a matcher instead of isA.

Answer (score 16):

To verify a static method using Mockito -> MockedStatic.

If the method has parameters and you want to verify it then it will be verify by this way:

```
@Test
void testMethod() {
  try (MockedStatic<StaticProperties> theMock = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticProperties.class)) {
    theMock.when(StaticProperties.getProperty("abc", "xyz", "lmn"))).thenReturn("OK");

    //code .....

    theMock.verify(() -> StaticProperties.getProperty("abc", "xyz", "lmn"));
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I see this upvoted and has been answered recently, however, I see that this way of calling verify on the mocked object is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to use PowerMockito for this Mockito alone wont be able to verify this

   ```
   PowerMockito.doNothing().when(SocialUtility.class,
                                 "removeOtherProviderAuthTokenFromSession", 
                                 any(MockHttpServletRequest.class),
                                 anyString());
   ```
2. You can mock your `getSocialAuthServiceProvider()` or spy it when you call your `SocialDataAccessController`

Comment: SocialDataAccessController mocksdac=Mockito.mock(SocialDataAccessController.class); SocialAuthServiceProvider sasp=Mockito.mock(SocialAuthServiceProvider.class); Mockito.when(mocksdac.getSocialAuthServiceProvider()).thenReturn(sasp); Mockito.verify(sasp).getOAuthServiceProvider(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(String.class)); still not successful

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 2nd question:

> I also want to use verify on getOAuthServiceProvider(appCode, provider). How can I do this?

Answer may be like this:

```
Mockito.verify(this.getSocialAuthServiceProvider())
       .getOAuthServiceProvider(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(String.class));
```

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Myeclipse doesn't recognise this line shows red mark under this.getSocialAuthServiceProvider(), i doubt if this is a correct way of doing.

Comment: Actually this.getSocialAuthServiceProvider() is not a mocked object and verify take mock object as a argument

Comment: So I think you have to mock this.getSocialAuthServiceProvider()