# How to unit test a Java method which calls a different class's static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I use plain Java and Junit.

```
   Class A {
       public void tesetMe(arg1, arg2) {
        arg3 = getArg3(arg1);
        B.staticMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3);
   }

   Class B {
     public static void staticMethod(String arg1, String arg2, int arg3) {
        //---
     }
   }
```

I am testing Class A's testMe method.
I want to verify if B's staticMethod is called with specific values of arg1, arg2 and arg3.
I cannot have a data member of type Class B.
I can use mockito but not powermock or any other library. I do not have a container where I can inject an instance of Class B. I have this like a plain simple java programs calling each other.

Comment: Usually, the answer here is that you're testing the wrong thing, and you _shouldn't_ be testing calls to static methods.  You should either change how B is organized to make it an instance method, or test the effects that `tesetMe` is supposed to have, whether it calls `staticMethod` or not.

Answer (score 1):

So I looked this up and I think this can solve your problem. One can mock a static class by calling mockStatic function, here is a quick example:

```
MockedStatic<StaticClass> x = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
```

After that, you can call all the usual functons you would on x variable like that:

```
x.verify(() -> StaticClass.staticFunction("x"));
```

I found [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods) and also found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610042/how-to-use-mockito-verify-on-static-methods).
Hope this helps!